# Error : Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, type-conversion

Error : Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

Getting error at this line why and what should be changed?

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,4),((CurrentLoans.Price - PreviousLoans.Price) / PreviousLoans.Price) * 100))
```

Comment: can anyone help me to identify what I need to change :( please

Comment: Please post better info next time.  Normally you get a line number with the error.  Also it's nice to see you attempted to resolve it yourself.

Comment: If you want people to spend time helping you you could put a little more effort into the question. What have you tried so far? Where does it fall over? What are the input values. I suggest you do some debugging, I would look at CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,4) for starters.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's at least one issue:

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,4))`

The `Decimal(8,4)` indicates 8 numeric digits, 4 to the right of  the decimal.  This does **NOT** account for the actual decimal character,  so you potentially have a value like:

`1234.5678`

which is a valid `Decimal(8,4)` but won't fit in a `varchar(8)`.

Comment: @ashuthinks - How About using VARCHAR(9) instead since you have 9 characters??

Comment: Use a `VARCHAR(9)` or `DECIMAL(7,3)` or `DECIMAL(7,4)`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I just wanted to say thanks. I was having this exact problem and what was most annoying was that it gave the error when selecting from a VIEW , but did not give the error when I used the select statement from the VIEW and pasted it and inserted it into a TEMP TABLE!!

example:

```
select * from dvView --worked
select * from dvView where product = '5' --Broke!
--BUT
select * from #Temp_table_dvView --worked!
select * from #Temp_table_dvView where product = '5' --worked!
```

in the end, I had to changed a part in the view from

```
select cast(productNumber as nvarchar(1), etc...
```

to

```
select cast(productNumber as nvarchar(2), etc...
```

and it worked.

but weird that the error I got was

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.
```

instead of the one that reads

```
Data would be truncated
```

or whatever...

food for thought.

Comment: Stupid SQL Server!  How can a `varchar` have an Arithmetic problem??